# What's the complete / correct method of sending email via PHP?

Tags: php

I've tried the `mail` function and it works fine. Now what all I need to add to it? When the content of mail is formed by user input.

[Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) says that lines (separated by `\n`) shouldn't be larger than 70 characters. So should I do wordwrap before using the mail function? Should I take care of full stops at the start of the lines? What else?

The doc also recommends PEAR's mail package for complex mails and sending large volumes of mail together. I've never used PEAR, how it's? What are the alternatives and how to choose among them?

Comment: Yeah @mario , a part this question is a duplicate of a part of the question you've mentioned. But this question is about complete method of using the `mail` function and that question is _"how can I know when the mail functionality is broken as soon as it breaks?"_

Comment: If that was your primary question, you shouldn't have crammed in another topic.

Answer (score 0):

The php native function `mail()`

This one maybe is not the most object oriented but is native and is the first one that you have to take a look.

[php mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: I know about the `mail` function. I'm asking that what should I do before using it? Like wrapping long lines of mail content, protecting from header injections etc.